# AttributeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

[I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCzkg.png)

I don't understand the cause of the error.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask especially part about not posting images of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `to` argument of `models.ForeignKey(...)`, i.e. the first positional argument should actually be a `models.Model` subclass, and not a model's attribute. So in the line mentioned in the debug log, you should change the `models.ForeignKey(Kutaphone.katagori, ...)` to `models.ForeignKey(Kutaphone)`.